# Show that $B(t)$ is a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $W(t)$ be a Brownian motion, and define $$B(t) = \int_0^t sign(W(s))dW(s) $$ where $$ sign(x) = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x \geq 0$ } \\
-1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

1. Show that $B(t)$ is a Brownian motion?
2. Show that $E(B_tX_t)=0$

For question 1, I know how to prove $B(t)$ has independent increments, but how to prove its increments are normal?

For question 2, using Ito's product rule, $$ d(B_tX_t) = B_tdX_t+X_tdB_t+dB_tdX_t $$
Since $B_t$ and $X_t$ are correlated, how do I deal with $dB_tdX_t$ in above equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the $X_t$ in part 2?

Comment: You should think about Lévy's characterization of a BM. Regards